# renaming video files in bulk taking input from a playlist file

Tags: shell-script, rename, mv

Files in directory :

```
$ ls | sort -n

1.mp4
2 .mp4
3 .mp4
4 .mp4
5 .mp4
6 .mp4
7 .mp4
8 .mp4
9 .mp4
10 .mp4
```

A list of file names in a playlist file :

```
$ cat playlist.m3u8

1- Introduction-OxIDLw0M-m0.mp4
2 - How React Works-pKYiKbf7sP0.mp4
3 - React Setup (with CDN)-SAX6RMEFVM4.mp4
4 - React Components-Fis_Q3rkgtM.mp4
5 - State-yuN4EMjR4K4.mp4
6 - React Dev Tools--XQ2zCdxw0I.mp4
7 - DOM Events--ZB8I2PmiOw.mp4
8 - Changing State (and 'this')-XJzDF9bj368.mp4
9 - Intro to Forms-BVbdZ1133JU.mp4
10 - Create React App-5QwNCX3UbXc.mp4
```

The file names start with numbers.
How do I rename the files in directory by names listed in playlist file with their  corresponding numbers so the outcome would be :

```
$ ls | sort -n


1- Introduction-OxIDLw0M-m0.mp4
2 - How React Works-pKYiKbf7sP0.mp4
3 - React Setup (with CDN)-SAX6RMEFVM4.mp4
4 - React Components-Fis_Q3rkgtM.mp4
5 - State-yuN4EMjR4K4.mp4
6 - React Dev Tools--XQ2zCdxw0I.mp4
7 - DOM Events--ZB8I2PmiOw.mp4
8 - Changing State (and 'this')-XJzDF9bj368.mp4
9 - Intro to Forms-BVbdZ1133JU.mp4
10 - Create React App-5QwNCX3UbXc.mp4
```

Comment: You can use `mv` or `rename` and for loop in shell script for example.

Comment: Or maybe `paste`?

Comment: `2 .mp4` or `2.mp4`?

Comment: @Arkadiusz , it's 2  .mp4 , yes there is gap between

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak, Just wanted specify I am open to any type of solutions.

Comment: @Arkadiusz, your previous answer worked like a charm. This is a slightly different case here.

Comment: Because of you want to be open, do not specify any particular tools, for your future endevours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while read -r i ; do
    file=$(echo $i | cut -d- -f1).mp4
    if [ -e "$file" ]; then
        mv "$file" "$i"
    fi      
done < playlist.m3u8
```

---

```
for i in ?*.mp4; do
    mv "$i" "$(grep -xm1 "${i%.*}"'-.*\.mp4' playlist.m3u8)"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `bash4+`, here is one way using `mapfile` aka `readarray`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob

rawfiles=(*.mp4)
mapfile -t files < <(printf '%s\n' "${rawfiles[@]}"| sort -n)
mapfile -t playlistfile < <(sort -n playlist.m3u8)

for i in "${!files[@]}"; do
   mv -v  "${files[$i]}" "${playlistfile[$i]}"
done
```

Output on Linux

```
renamed '1.mp4' -> '1- Introduction-OxIDLw0M-m0.mp4'
renamed '2 .mp4' -> '2 - How React Works-pKYiKbf7sP0.mp4'
renamed '3 .mp4' -> '3 - React Setup (with CDN)-SAX6RMEFVM4.mp4'
renamed '4 .mp4' -> '4 - React Components-Fis_Q3rkgtM.mp4'
renamed '5 .mp4' -> '5 - State-yuN4EMjR4K4.mp4'
renamed '6 .mp4' -> '6 - React Dev Tools--XQ2zCdxw0I.mp4'
renamed '7 .mp4' -> '7 - DOM Events--ZB8I2PmiOw.mp4'
renamed '8 .mp4' -> '8 - Changing State (and '\''this'\'')-XJzDF9bj368.mp4'
renamed '9 .mp4' -> '9 - Intro to Forms-BVbdZ1133JU.mp4'
renamed '10 .mp4' -> '10 - Create React App-5QwNCX3UbXc.mp4'
```

Here is the oneliner

```
rawfiles=(*.mp4); mapfile -t files < <(printf '%s\n' "${rawfiles[@]}"| sort -n); mapfile -t playlistfile < <( sort -n playlist.m3u8); for i in "${!files[@]}"; do  mv -v  "${files[$i]}" "${playlistfile[$i]}"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `paste` like that:

```
paste <(ls -1 *mp4 | sort -n) playlist.m3u8  | sed 's,\t,\t",' | sed 's,^,",' | sed 's,mp4,mp4",g' | xargs -L1 mv
```

Result:

```
$ ll
total 4.0K
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users   0 Feb 24 15:09 9 - Intro to Forms-BVbdZ1133JU.mp4
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users   0 Feb 24 15:09 8 - Changing State (and 'this')-XJzDF9bj368.mp4
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users   0 Feb 24 15:09 7 - DOM Events--ZB8I2PmiOw.mp4
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users   0 Feb 24 15:09 6 - React Dev Tools--XQ2zCdxw0I.mp4
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users   0 Feb 24 15:09 5 - State-yuN4EMjR4K4.mp4
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users   0 Feb 24 15:09 4 - React Components-Fis_Q3rkgtM.mp4
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users   0 Feb 24 15:09 3 - React Setup (with CDN)-SAX6RMEFVM4.mp4
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users   0 Feb 24 15:09 2 - How React Works-pKYiKbf7sP0.mp4
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users   0 Feb 24 15:09 10 - Create React App-5QwNCX3UbXc.mp4
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users   0 Feb 24 15:09 1- Introduction-OxIDLw0M-m0.mp4
```

Although it would work in this particular case notice that [parsing output of ls is not a good idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead).